# Use search matches as parameters in external command

Tags: command-line, external-command, filetype-tex

I want to define a Vim command that will install all LaTeX packages used in a `.tex` file.

To install packages I can do `sudo tlmgr install package1 package2 package3` etc. in the command line.

So now I need a way to get the names of all packages used in the file and use them with `tlmgr`.

It would be even better if I don't have to leave the buffer to type the `sudo` password, but that's not strictly necessary.

---

The packages are added like so: `\usepackage{whatever}`.

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but I'm doing this to match the lines that call packages:

`/^\\usepackage\(\[.*\]\)\?{\(.*\)}$`

But it matches the whole line. Then I added that second pair of escaped parenthesis hoping to capture just the name of the package… but now I have no idea how to call `tlmgr` using just those names.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509690/how-can-you-list-the-matches-of-vims-search

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid leaving the buffer for entering the password, you can use `sudo`'s [`-S` flag](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/sudo.8.html):

```
 -S, --stdin
             Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password
             from the standard input instead of using the terminal device.
             The password must be followed by a newline character.
```

Then your function could look like:

```
function! InstallPackages()
    let winview = winsaveview()
    call inputsave()
    let cmd = ['sudo -S tlmgr install']
    %call add(cmd, matchstr(getline('.'), '\\usepackage\(\[.*\]\)\?{\zs.*\ze\}'))
    echomsg join(cmd)
    let pass = inputsecret('Enter sudo password:') . "\n"
    echo system(join(cmd), pass)
    call inputrestore()
    call winrestview(winview)
endfunction
```

Since the second argument to `system` is passed as standard input, we can use Vim's [`inputsecret()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#inputsecret%28%29) function to read the password and send it to `sudo` (but we need to add the trailing newline ourselves, or `sudo` will wait around for it).

Comment: It does not search for the pattern `\usepackage` in the whole file, or am I missing something?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt `%call ... getline(.)` - I'm calling matchstr on each line.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Just two things: it should be `call inputsave()` there in the function's second line. And the second was my mistake, the command is actually `tlmgr install`. I changed those two lines and it works like a charm!

Comment: @danielbmarques my bad, corrected.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure because I don't have the `tlmgr` shell command to test it, but you could try this:

```
command! InstallTexPackages call s:install_tex_packages()
function! s:install_tex_packages() abort
    let winview = winsaveview()
    let packages = []
    sil! %s/^\\usepackage{\zs.*\ze}$/\=add(packages, submatch(0))/gn
    exe '!sudo tlmgr' join(packages)
    call winrestview(winview)
endfunction
```

---

It installs the `:InstallTexPackages` command which calls the `s:install_tex_packages()` function.

The pattern used to search for the packages names is `^\\usepackage{\zs.*\ze}$` which should match `foo`, `bar`, `baz` in the following buffer:

```
\usepackage{foo}
\usepackage{bar}
\usepackage{baz}
```

The atoms `\zs` and `\ze` allow you to use the text before and after the packages names as anchors, and not include them in the match.

The names are stored in the list `packages`, and the substitution command `:s` is called to progressively populate the list.

Each time a package name is found, `:s` evaluates (`\=`) the expression `add(packages, submatch(0))`. `add()` adds an item to a list. Here the list is `packages` and the item is `submatch(0)`, which is the text which has just been matched.

No substitution is made thanks to the `n` flag (`:h :s_flags`).

To be able to evaluate an expression with the `n` flag, your Vim version needs to be newer than 7.3.627. If it's not, you would have to replace the substitution command with this:

```
call cursor(1, 1)
let matchline = search('^\\usepackage{\zs.*\ze}$', 'cW')
while matchline
    let packages += [matchstr(getline(matchline), '^\\usepackage{\zs.*\ze}$')]
    let matchline = search('^\\usepackage{\zs.*\ze}$', 'W')
endwhile
```

Comment: What happened? Why did you delete this? :(

Comment: @muru Sorry, I realised that the answer had too many flaws. I don't know the syntax of `tlmgr`, i think but not
sure that you have to add the argument `install` after it. The substitution command or the while loop
are necessary only if there're several matches per line. But in this case there can only be one match
at most per line. So your syntax `:%call add(…)` is better, because it should work on more versions of Vim, while being shorter. Finally, your answer allows the user to stay in Vim, thanks to `inputsecret()` and `system()`.

Comment: @muru So, all in all, I found this answer not very good. I undeleted it, in case someone finds something useful in it.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about `tlmgr` syntax, I'm sure OP can figure that   out. :) But its always nice to have multiple ways to tackle a problem.

Comment: I accepted muru's answer because of the things you mentioned, but I loved your explanations, I didn't know about `\zs` and `\ze`. Also you're right, I forgot to add the `install` argument.